# HTML slider in email which contain images / text / illustration

Tags: javascript, html, email, slider, newsletter

How can I produce a slider containing photos/illustrations and text which I could send via email rather than the website?

In [this example newsletter](http://themeforest.net/item/innovate-email-newsletter/2447801), click on `Live Preview`.

Can we send the newsletter which is shown in that link via email, because it is named as newsletter and if we can't send then is it a waste ?

Comment: Sliders require JavaScript, which afaik is disabled in mail clients. Offer your readers a link to click on to take them to your website, and give them a reason to click through.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with any HTML in an email is that it is totally dependent on what HTML the recipient's email client will parse. Even if the client (correctly) parses the HTML for a slider, you then have to contend with the issue of loading an external resource (images). I want to say this is not possible, but by all means, fire off an email to a Gmail account and see what happens.